# Ordinary Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider a system of differential equation
*y'(t) = By(t)* where *B* is a 2X2 matrix defined as: *B = [α , -β ; β , α]*

where α,β ∈ ℝ and (α,β) ≠  (0,0).

A) If the roots of B are purely imaginary verify that the the solution of this system *y=( y1 , y2 )* is of the form *y1(t) = c1 cos(c2 + βt) and y2(t) = c1 sin(c2 + βt)*.

B) Characterise the orbit of *y*, namely *y(ℝ+)*. Graph the orbit in *ℝ2*.

C) Comment on the stability properties of *y* when the roots of *B* are purely imaginary.

D) If the roots are not purely imaginary then verify that the solution of this system *y=( y1,y2 ) is of the form y1(t) = c1 exp(αt)cos(c2 + βt) and y2(t) = c1 exp(αt)sin(c2 + βt)*.

E) Derive and graph the orbit of *y* when the roots of *B* are not purely imaginary.

F) Comment on the stability properties of *y* when the roots of *B* are not purely imaginary.

G) What determines the direction of rotation of the orbit as *t ↑ ∞* ?

Comment: Where did this set of problems come from? What have you done so far?

Comment: Hello Mr Cohen,
Source: An entrance exam.

I could do the first part, assuming the roots are purely imaginary. But I have no clue with respect to second and third part.
Similarly D part was also solvable but again I got stuck with E,F and G parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints (given that this is from an entrance exam).

**Part A**

We have: $B = \begin{bmatrix}\alpha & -\beta\\\beta & \alpha\end{bmatrix}$

We can find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of this matrix as:

- $\lambda_1 = \alpha - i \beta, ~~v_1 = (-i, 1)$
- $\lambda_2 = \alpha + i \beta, ~~v_2 = (i, 1)$

Since the roots are purely imaginary, that is $\alpha = 0$, we can write the solution $y(t)$ as follows:

$y(t) = \begin{bmatrix} y_1(t) \\ y_2(t)\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} c_1  \cos \beta t - c_2 \sin \beta t \\ c_1 \sin \beta t + c_2 \cos \beta t \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} c_1 \cos(c_2 + \beta t) \\c_1 \sin(c_2 + \beta t) \end{bmatrix}$

Note: the last part uses the fact that we can shift $\cos$ and $\sin$ terms to combine them. We can easily verify this solution by replacing it in the original equation and verifying it satisfies it.

**Part B**

The orbits are going to be spirals when the eigenvalues are purely imaginary as can be seen from this phase portrait.

[image].

**Part C**

These are stable (but not asymptotically stable); sometimes it is referred to as neutrally stable.

**Part D**

Form the eigenvalue/eigenvector pairs determined above, we have:

$y(t) = \begin{bmatrix} y_1(t) \\ y_2(t)\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} c_1 e^{\alpha t} \cos (\beta t) - c_2 e^{\alpha t} \sin (\beta t) \\ c_1 e^{\alpha t} \sin (\beta t) + c_2 e^{\alpha t} \cos (\beta t) \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} c_1 e^{\alpha t} \cos(c_2 + \beta t) \\c_1 e^{\alpha t} \sin(c_2 + \beta t) \end{bmatrix}$

**Part E**

We can draw a phase portrait for various cases (we already did $\alpha = 0$, so have to see $\alpha > 0$ and $\alpha < 0$).

For $\alpha > 0$, we have:

[image]

For $\alpha < 0$, we have:

[image]

**Part F**

- $\alpha > 0$, we have an unstable spiral point at the origin.
- $\alpha < 0$, we have stable spiral point at the origin.

**Part G**

The sign of $\alpha$ as that leads to the time dependent exponential term. Also, the magnitude of $\alpha$ determines the rate.

Comment: Awesome hints, graphics! +1

Answer (score 0):

As your eigenvalues are purely imaginary,they have only imaginary parts . That's why the phase portrait looks like circles or ellipses (depends on values of imaginary parts)
[image: phase portrait]

When eigenvalues are not purely imaginary, you'll have focus as a phase portrait.

Comment: It's quite easy to draw such portrait in Mathematica